# Checkbox "NoMethodError" in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a CMS and I faced a problem while making a role management for users. I have a boolean field `:admin` in my `User` model, and I've made a checkbox in my form to set created user as an administrator. Here is the `users_controller`:

```
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to users_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def edit
end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to users_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my form :

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  # Here go fields for username, email and password
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Set as administrator" %> <br />
    <%= f.hidden_field :admin, '' %> 
    # I also tried with <%= f.hidden_field :admin, false %>
    <%= f.check_box :admin, checked = true %> 
    # Or <%= f.check_box :admin, data: { switch: true } %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

But any of these options returns me the following:

```
NoMethodError in Multiflora::Users#edit

undefined method `merge' for "":String
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: you want to select tag for role did you create `enum` form role

Comment: Take hidden field as `<%= f.hidden_field :admin, value: '' %>` or simply `<%= f.hidden_field :admin %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take hidden field as

`<%= f.hidden_field :admin, value: '' %>`,
 or simply

`<%= f.hidden_field :admin %>`

and checkbox as `<%= f.check_box :admin, :checked => true %>`

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  # Here go fields for username, email and password
  <p>
    <%= f.label "Set as administrator" %> <br />
    <%= f.hidden_field :admin, value: '' %>/<%= f.hidden_field :admin %> 
    <%= f.check_box :admin, :checked => true %> 
  </p>
<% end %>
```